# Como subtrair números decimais?

Tags: javascript

Fiz uma função para fazer FadeOut numa `<div>` assim que terminar de carregar a página porém não consigo obter o valor exato do final do FadeOut (que seria 0) sempre me dá um número como esse: 0.009999999999999247;

**Como posso fazer para subtrair de forma correta e obter o 0?**

```
function fadeOut(id){
    //pega o elemento da página
    obj = document.getElementById(id);
    //seta a opacidade como 0
    obj.style.opacity = 1.00;

    fazFadeOut = function (){
        if(obj.style.opacity != 0){  
            var atual = Number(obj.style.opacity);   
            var newopac = atual - Number(0.01);
            obj.style.opacity = String(newopac);    
            if(obj.style.opacity == 0){
                obj.style.display = 'none';
            }
            setTimeout('fazFadeOut()', 10);
        }
    }
    fazFadeOut();
}
```

[EXEMPLO em funcionamento](http://jsbin.com/wibixafo/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: a expressão `atual - Number(0.01)` que te retorna `0.00999...` ?

Comment: @Paulo Sim, era para setar a opacidade da <div> 0 mas me dá isso 0.009999999999999247

Comment: Na verdade isto é um paliativo. Não se deve representar dinheiro desta forma: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/110463/101.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number em Javascript é um ponto flutuante (http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/The_Complete_Javascript_Number_Reference) e, de acordo com o link "tão precisos quanto possível".
Portanto:

```
var soma = 0.06 + 0.01
// soma fica com o valor de 0.06999999999999999
```

Uma solução para isso é arredondar o valor usando toFixed(numeroDeDigitosNaCasaDecimal)

```
var soma = (0.06 + 0.01).toFixed(2);
// soma fica com o valor de 0.07

var maisCasas = (0.06 + 0.01).toFixed(5);
// maisCasas fica com o valor de 0.07000
```

Comment: Valeu @Ricardo, isso resolveu :) só precisei mudar String(newopac) para Number(newopac).toFixed(2);

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar `Math.floor()` para arredondar para baixo obtendo o `0` que você quer:

Porém você quer o valor decimal, então você deve utilizar apenas menos casas decimais, até porque o javascript não é mais preciso depois de algumas casas decimais, portanto:

```
window.onload = function(){
//quando o documento terminar de carregar esconde a div
    setTimeout(function(){
        fadeOut('load');
        document.getElementById('content').style.webkitFilter = 'none';
    },1000);
};

function fadeOut(id){
    //pega o elemento da página
    obj = document.getElementById(id);
    //seta a opacidade como 0
    obj.style.opacity = 1.00;

    fazFadeOut = function (){
        if(obj.style.opacity !== 0){     
            var atual = Number(obj.style.opacity);   
            var newopac = atual - Number(0.01).toFixed(x);//onde x seria o numero de casas decimais que você quer.
            obj.style.opacity = String(newopac);    
            if(obj.style.opacity === 0){
                obj.style.display = 'none';
            }
            setTimeout(fazFadeOut, 10);
        }
    };
    fazFadeOut();
}
```

## Observação:

Corrigi algumas warnings que seu JSBin acusou, o código ficaria como está acima já corrigido.

**Mudanças:** comparações devem ser feitas com `===` e `!==` neste contexto, e também estava faltando umas semicolons. Outra coisa **importante** não use `setTimeout("fazFadeOut()", 10);` **nunca**. Você deve passar a função em si, que seria utilizando `setTimeout(fazFadeOut, 10);`

Comment: ok - eu nao havia entendido direito, desculpe. editei minha resposta :)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Paulo!