# Arredondar um numero à decima 4023.8599999999997€

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho 4023.8599999999997€ para arredondar para 4023.86, tentei:

```
Math.round(sum1)
```

mas o resultado foi :4024€

Tambem tentei `Math.round(sum1,2)` mas não deu.

Como fazer isto  Estou a usar JavaScript.

Comment: Nunca vi classe `Math` nem o ponto como invocador de métodos no php

Comment: Acho que ele quer algo assim `var valor = 4023.8599999999997;

console.log(Math.round(valor * 100)/100);`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### PHP

```
<?php 

    $var = 4023.8599999999997;

    echo round($var, 2).'<br>'; // 4023.86

    echo ceil($var).'<br>'; // 4024

    echo floor($var); // 4023
```

**`round()`** - Arredonda automaticamente, faz as funções do `ceil` e do `floor`.

**`ceil()`** - Arredonda pra cima, ignorando casas decimais

**`floor()`** - Arredonda pra baixo, ignorando casas decimais

### JS

```
var num = 4023.8599999999997;

Math.round(num); // 4024

num.toFixed(2); // 4023.86
```

Answer (score 8):

Na verdade a única forma de resolver o problema de fato é mudar o tipo de dados que está trabalhando. Não se trabalha com valores de ponto flutuante com dinheiro. Isto é um erro grave. Outras soluções só mascaram o problemas, ou seja joga o problema pra baixo do tapete. Pode causar enorme prejuízo financeiro. Veja mais em [Números diferentes se tornam iguais após conversão com doubleval](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/78735/101) e [Como representar dinheiro em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11018/101) e ainda [Qual a forma correta de usar os tipos float, double e decimal?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101).

Comment: Vou verificar isso entao a solucao é passar o valor do jscript para o php? Obg

Comment: Em tudo precisa trabalhar com um tipo decimal ou trabalhar com inteiros. Nessas perguntas *linkadas* tem mais informações porque isto acontece. E ocorre em todas as linguagens, simplificadamente é um "problema" do processador. As soluções que parecem resolver o problema só criam uma ilusão. As contas serão feitas todas erradas. Já vi empresa tomando multa de fiscal por consequência disto.

Comment: neste caso não é nada de muito serio mas obrigado pela dica!

Comment: Como não é sério?

Comment: não é nada muito oficial , apenas estava a calcular o valor estimado de pagamentos , claro que se estiver 100% correto melhor :)

Comment: Se é melhor, então importa. Se é dinheiro, importa. Mesmo que seja estimativas, está dizendo que todo o sistema está correto e só as estimativas forma feitas de forma errada? Ou será que nunca ninguém percebeu que todo o sistema está errado? E que mesmo que esteja certo, se este valor for usado em outra parte, contamina tudo. Não existe 99% certo, ou é 100% certo ou é 0% certo.

Comment: sim :) de qualquer forma aqui para isto utilizei isto :(Math.round(sum1 * 100)/100) parece resolver o problema

Comment: Soluções por coincidência não são soluções.

Answer (score 6):

Fiz um teste com o `round` e funcionou ok:

```
$sum1 = 4023.8599999999997;
echo round($sum1, 2);
```

> 4023.86

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/asZnvP)