# Como eu arredondo a terceira casa decimal em php?

Tags: php, arredondamento

Preciso de uma ajuda, tenho seguinte problema, preciso fazer um arredondamento da terceira casa decimal para cima, como eu faço?

EX:

De 3.49 converte para 3.50
De 3.48 converte para 3.50
De 3.43 converte para 3.50
De 3.42 converte para 3.50

Quando eu uso a função `round` ele converte para 4.00

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Arredondar um numero à decima 4023.8599999999997€](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110463/arredondar-um-numero-%c3%a0-decima-4023-8599999999997%e2%82%ac)

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida a outra pergunta é sobre Javascript, esta é sobre PHP.

Comment: @Renan mas tem a resposta em PHP tb :)

Comment: @JefersonAlmeida a outra pergunta foi mal respondida. O AP pede a resposta em Javascript, até onde entendi. Além disso, em uma busca simples, incluindo tag, você não a encontraria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tens de usar o segundo argumento dessa função `round` que é exatamente o numero de casas decimais, a precisão.

Exemplo:

```
echo round(3.425);     // 3
echo round(3.425 , 1); // 3.4
echo round(3.425 , 2); // 3.43
echo round(3.425 , 3); // 3.425
```

para converter ao estilo de `ceil` mas com casas decimais podes fazer assim:

```
function ceil_dec($val, $dec) { 
    $pow = pow(10, $dec); 
    return ceil($pow * $val) / $pow; 
} 

echo ceil_dec(3.43, 1); // 3.5
```

Comment: Mas assim não arredonda 3.49 para 3.50 como pedido, certo?

Comment: Mas eu necessito arredondar para cima como faz?

Comment: @TutiJapaWada se precisas arredondar sempre para cima deves usar o `ceil`, não o `round`.

Comment: @TutiJapaWada acho que você pode: multiplicar por 100, utilizar a função [ceil](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php) e dividir por 100 de novo.

Comment: @Sergio acho que precisa de algo a mais, a `ceil` arredonda uma fração para o próximo inteiro.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss `round(3.49, 1);` dá `3.5` mas estou a ver que o AP quer arredondar sempre para cima.

Comment: @TutiJapaWada queres arredondar sempre para cima com 1 casa decimal, é isso?

Comment: Sim, sempre para cima, ceil é inteiro e round não funciona também ;/

Comment: @TutiJapaWada adicionei mais uma variante, dá uma olhada.

Comment: @Sergio, perfeito agora funcionou valeu! :D