# Como arredondar um valor em TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Como eu arredondo um número, como adiciono no código (calculadora imc em typescript)?. E como adicionei `if`s para informar o imc saudável, obeso, sobre peso, etc...

```js
const calculadora = document.querySelector<HTMLFormElement>('#calculadora')!
const peso = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#peso')!
const altura = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#altura')!
const mensagem = document.querySelector<HTMLParagraphElement>('#mensagem')!
const retorno = document.querySelector<HTMLParagraphElement>('#retorno')!

function calculoIMC (peso: number, altura: number) {
  return peso / (altura*altura)
  
}

calculadora.addEventListener('click', (e: Event ) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let novoPeso = parseFloat(peso.value)
    let novaAltura = parseFloat(altura.value)
    mensagem.innerText = "Seu IMC e de :" + (calculoIMC (novoPeso, novaAltura))
})
```

Comment: Nao use imagens do seu codigo, poste ele na pergunta. Fica mais facil de ajudar voce. [Veja essas dicas pra se orientar melhor.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8496/checklist-de-perguntas-do-stack-overflow?cb=1)

Comment: const calculadora = document.querySelector<HTMLFormElement>('#calculadora')!
const peso = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#peso')!
const altura = document.querySelector<HTMLInputElement>('#altura')!
const mensagem = document.querySelector<HTMLParagraphElement>('#mensagem')!
const retorno = document.querySelector<HTMLParagraphElement>('#retorno')!

function calculoIMC (peso: number, altura: number) {
  return peso / (altura*altura)
  
}
VOU COLOCAR DIVIDIDO

Comment: calculadora.addEventListener('click', (e: Event ) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let novoPeso = parseFloat(peso.value)
    let novaAltura = parseFloat(altura.value)
    mensagem.innerText = "Seu IMC e de :" + (calculoIMC (novoPeso, novaAltura))
})

Comment: Ok Vitoria, vejo que voce esta comecando a usar o site agora. Nao tem problema voce ainda nao saber como postar o codigo, mas eu fiz uma edicao da sua pergunta, e destaquei o seu codigo. Veja como ficou pra voce se basear futuramente. E sempre bom postar o codigo em si e nao imagens do mesmo, ok? :D

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Arredondar um numero à decima 4023.8599999999997€](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110463/arredondar-um-numero-%c3%a0-decima-4023-8599999999997%e2%82%ac)

Comment: tem várias perguntas/respostas aqui no site de como arredondar usando javascript

Comment: Fora que a pergunta não se trata de TypeScript. Como o arredondamento é feito em runtime (e não em compile time), trata-se de JavaScript...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usando simples métodos do JavaScript/TypeScript, providos pela classe `Math`, você pode arredondar pra cima ou pra baixo qualquer número não inteiro.

Veja:

```js
function calculoIMC (peso, altura) {
  return peso / (altura*altura) 
}

console.log(calculoIMC(80.2, 1.78));

console.log(Math.ceil(calculoIMC(80.2, 1.78)));

console.log(Math.floor(calculoIMC(80.2, 1.78)));
```

Veja que `Math.ceil` arredonda para cima, enquanto `Math.floor` arredonda para baixo.

Estes mesmos métodos funcionam no TypeScript, apenas coloquei como JS puro para poder exemplificar no código acima.

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
calculadora.addEventListener('click', (e: Event ) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    let novoPeso = parseFloat(peso.value)
    let novaAltura = parseFloat(altura.value)
    mensagem.innerText = "Seu IMC e de :" + Math.floor(calculoIMC (novoPeso, novaAltura)) // ou Math.ceil
})
```

Comment: muito obrigada! poderia me dizer como eu valido para inserir os valores corretamente? e como add if por exemplo (if (parseFloat(imc) > 18) { retorno.inertext = "voce esta em magreza"}